# Stored procedures: IF statement within FOR...IN

Tags: sql, for-loop, if-statement, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

My stored procedure has a `FOR` loop but I'd like to include an `IF` statement within the loop where if the `IF` statement is true, then only loop over one row - otherwise, loop over all 3 rows.

Example provided below:

```
  FOR snippets IN (
    if digit = 'only one' then
        select
          "one" as number
    else
        select
          "one" as number
        union all
        select
          "two" as number
        union all 
        select
          "three" as number
    end if;)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two major way:

1. Filter data supplied into for to iterate over. Something like this:

```sql
FOR snippets IN (
        select "one" as number
        union all
        select "two" as number
        where digit = 'only one'
        union all 
        select "three" as number
        where digit = 'only one')
```

2. Add check inside of for, that will break loop when needed:

```sql
FOR snippets IN (
      select "one" as number
      union all
      select "two" as number
      union all 
      select "three" as number)
DO
    if digit = 'only one' and snippets <> 'one' then
        BREAK;
    end if;
END FOR;
```

Comment: Can I add a case when statement in the loop where if a variable is true it only loops through one of the select statements, if the variable is false it loops through all 3 select statements? I've tried it out but no luck.

Comment: @tamboo, do you mean something like `if my_boolean_var and snippets <> 'one'` in my second snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround which uses a temp table like below.

```sql
DECLARE digit DEFAULT 'only one';

IF digit = 'only one' THEN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE snippets AS
    SELECT 'one' number;
ELSE
  CREATE TEMP TABLE snippets AS
    SELECT 'one' number UNION ALL
    SELECT 'two' number UNION ALL
    SELECT 'three' number;
END IF;

FOR snippet IN (SELECT * FROM snippets)
DO
  SELECT snippet.number;
END FOR;

-- script result
+--------+
| number |
+--------+
| one    |
+--------+
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I noticed when I declare digit as another value it doesn't result in all three inputs though....

Comment: It'wll return the query result with one row  3 times if you set `digit` with other value than `only one`.